# XPath cannot select right nodes

Tags: xpath, adhoc

Here is an example:

```
<html>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>07 Oct 13</td>
        <td>a</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>07 Sep 13</td>
        <td>b</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>07 Sep 13</td>
        <td>c</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>    
  </table>    
</html>
```

So I need to select td[2] elements if td[1] has unique date. In this example we must get only {a, b} because element "b" and  "c" has the same date. I can get only the unique dates:

```
//table//td[(position() = 1 and not(. = preceding::*/td))]

Output: {07 Oct 13, 07 Sep 13}
```

But how can I get only td[2] elements?

Comment: How about selecting the `tr` tags for which there is a `td[position() = 1]` which fullfills your condition and selecting `td[2]` from that `tr`

Comment: @Matthias can you provide an example?

Comment: @EugeneTskhovrebov With explanation it is a bit long for a comment, I put a working xPath as an answer and added a bit of explanation. Please check if this is doing what you want.

Answer (score 0):

As written earlier in a comment, I would select the matching parent elements and from there, get the interesting child nodes.

I experimented a bit with this XPath `//tr[td[1] and not(./td[1] = preceding::*/td)]/td[2]` should do what you want.

So I select a `tr` for which the 1st `td` was not matched before. Of this `tr` we then select the second `td` element.

With that xPath I have your desired output.

Comment: Good to hear that! XPath is a great tool for this, glad I could help.